# clang: error: -lm: 'linker' input unused while compiling on MacOSX

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a program mafTools on MacOSX using gnu make. I get the following error:

```
cd mafExtractor && make all

clang -std=c99 -stdlib=libstdc++ -O3 -c -O3 -Wall -Werror --pedantic -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -I ../../sonLib/lib -I ../inc -I ../external  src/mafExtractorAPI.c -o src/mafExtractorAPI.o.tmp -lm
```

This gives the error:

```
clang: error: -lm: 'linker' input unused [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
make[1]: \*** [src/mafExtractorAPI.o] Error 1
make: \*** [mafExtractor.all] Error 2
```

I looked at similar errors but couldn't fix it. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

This is the package: https://github.com/dentearl/mafTools/tree/master/mafExtractor
Everything else here compiled successfully.

This is the makefile:
https://github.com/dentearl/mafTools/blob/master/mafExtractor/Makefile

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 5):

Your `clang` commaand includes the `-c` option which means you do not want to link and resolve external references, you just want to produce an unlinked object file.

Your `-lm` option says you want to link with the maths library.

Basically, the aforementioned options are incompatible - you cannot both link with the math library and not link.

TLDR; Remove `-lm`